# Bootstrap 5 image alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I am working on a Django blog application and I have run into a problem with image alignment using Bootstrap 5.  I am new at CSS and none of the solutions I see in SO are helping.  My problem is I want the text under my images to always line up regardless of the height of the image itself.  Here is a  partial screen shot:

[image]

Here is the HTML code I developed:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Post List{% endblock title %}
  {% block content  %}

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Latest Posts -->
        <main class="posts-listing col-lg-8"> 
          {% if page_obj %}
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
      
              <!-- posts -->
              
              {% for post in page_obj  %}
              <div class="post col-xl-6">
                  <div class="card">
                   <a href="{{post.get_absolute_url}}">
                     <img src="{{post.thumbnail.url}}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="post-meta d-flex justify-content-between">
                    {% comment "" %}<div class="date meta-last"></div>{% endcomment %}
                      <div class="category">
                        {% for cat in post.categories.all %}
                        <a href="#">{{cat.title}} </a>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </div>
                  </div>
                    <a href={{post.get_absolute_url}}>
                        <h3 class="h4">{{post.title}}</h3>
                    </a>
                  <p class="text-muted">{{post.content|safe | truncatechars:256 }}</p>
                  <footer class="post-footer d-flex align-items-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'show-user-profile' post.author.user.id %}" class="profile d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                      <div class="avatar"><img src="{{post.author.profile_picture.url}}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></div>
                      <div class="title"><span>{{post.author.user.username}}</span></div>
                    </a>
  
                    <div class="date"><i class="icon-clock"></i>{{post.timestamp | timesince}} ago</div>
                    <div class="comments meta-last"><i class="icon-comment"></i>{{post.comment_count}}</div>
                  </footer>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
            
            </div>
           
          </div>
          {% else %}
            <p class="text-big">No Posts in this category</p>
          {% endif %}
        </main>
        {% include 'sidebar.html' with most_recent=most_recent category_count=category_count %}
      </div>
    </div>

    {% endblock content  %}
```

The comments I am getting make it seem like what I am trying to do is impossible, and perhaps it is.  Here is a screenshot from Adobe Lightroom that shows the concept - all the photos are placed in identically sized boxes regardless of aspect ratio.  No distortion, just different size margins to fill in unused space.  Now Lightroom isn't HTML but can't this be done?  As I mentioned, all of the sample galleries I see use photos with the same aspect ratio, but that should not be a requirement of a gallery.

[image]

I would appreciate some help.  Thanks

Comment: One way would be to ensure your images have matching aspect ratios.

Comment: That certainly would be nice.  But I won't have any control over what picture the user chooses to upload.

Comment: Take a look at: https://codepen.io/eyupucmaz/pen/oNbeXOb. https://freefrontend.com/css-cards/ has quite a few you might find helpful.

Comment: The codepen example is exactly what I am trying to do, BUT notice all the images have the same aspect ratio.  I've looked at dozens of these examples and they all have that same deficiency. In the real world you get both portrait and landscape orientations mixed. In my case all images must be the same height. For the portrait orientation, they can have white space around the sides - that's fine.  I don't want to stretch them I just want them all to be the same height.  Thank you.

Comment: There has to be a minimum/maximum height and width that you enforce. Most sites that allow image uploads either enforce a size/ratio rule and/or allow users to crop the image. You can play around with `object-contain`, `object-fit`, etc but that won't make up for the fact that an image is too small for the space it's trying to occupy.

Comment: You are talking about about auto cropping images. You can read about the perils of doing so when it involves images of persons.